# How to extract using regex this text from a complex set of strings?

Tags: php, regex

```
6 celery sticks, chopped
1 pear
300g/10.6oz strawberries
50g (1.7oz) porridge oats (uncooked)
1 tsp agave
100ml (3.4oz) Whole milk (soy/almond/rice/hemp/oat)
1 scoop of protein powder (approx. 20g/0.7oz)
½ avocado
100g/3.5oz of mushrooms, chopped
1 tsp extra virgin olive oil
```

**What I want to extract**

celery sticks, pear, strawberries, porridge oats, agave, Whole milk, protein powder, avocado, mushrooms, extra virgin olive oil.

**What I have tried**

`(^.*(\d|oz|\(|tsp|½|of)|(,|\().*$)`

**What I am getting**

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rok

Click **preg_split** tab when you run it.

Ideally I should just be able to do match[0] and get the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` functions:

```
^[\d½]+\S*\h+(?:\([^)]*\)|tsp|.*? of\b)?\h*([a-z]+(?:\h+[a-z]+)*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1cLC1I/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[\d½]+`: Match 1+ digits or `½`
- `\S*`: Match 0 or more non-space characters
- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal spaces
- `(?:\([^)]*\)|tsp|.*? of\b)?\h*`: Match extra bit of characters
- `([a-z]+(?:\h+[a-z]+)*)`: Match ingredient name

[PHP Live Demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ron)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190561/discussion-on-answer-by-anubhava-how-to-extract-using-regex-this-text-from-a-com).